# What to do if one's father is toxic & forces to marry someone who is not suitable in both POV islamic and worldly?if refused he abuses his wife & kids

Tags: quran, hadith, sharia, islamic-basis, torture

My father wants us all 4 siblings to marry his brother's sons and daughter.
And they are not even educated , they dont even pray and are very far away from islam .they dont even have jobs ,not a home , they have no manners and yet he forces us to marry them.
My father tortures us mentally and doesn't give money and doesnt support us the way he has to .
He beats my mother and us when he is under pressure of his brother . He even threats to kill our mother and us .

Is it allowed in islam to leave him then? And we all run away somewhere.